# Doing tasks when a Tkinter application is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, tkinter

When my Tkinter application ends it has to do some jobs (e. g. store some data to files). In some cases, the users should be asked if she/he really wants to close the application.

There are multiple ways to close a Tkinter application:

- The X on the window
- A button
- An entry in the menubar

How can I **catch** all this kind of "events"?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *

def on_delete_window():
    print('on_delete_window')
    print('save my data')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    Button(root, text='Destroy', command=root.destroy).pack()
    Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack()
    menu = Menu(root)
    menu.add_command(label='Destroy', command=root.destroy)
    menu.add_command(label='Quit', command=root.quit)
    root.config(menu=menu)

    # this catches ONLY the X in the window
    # but none of the two buttons!
    root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_delete_window)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround would be to define a `closing_procedure` method that accepts `callback` argument that carries on/off the callback based on the reply to a `messagebox` dialog, to which you're redirecting *all* closing operations for example.

## Example

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
    import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkMessageBox as tkmb


def closing_procedure(callback, *args, **kwargs):
    response = tkmb.askyesno("Quit", "Do you really want to close?")
    if response:
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        print("Closing cancelled!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Quit",
                                command=lambda : closing_procedure(root.quit))
    button.pack()
    root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',
                                    lambda : closing_procedure(root.destroy))
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to trap everything in a single call, bind to the `<Destroy>` event of the root window. No matter how it is destroyed, your function will be called. Be careful though -- events bound to the root window are caught by every widget. You'll want to do your final actions only when it is the root window that is destroyed.

If you want to ask the user if they are sure when they close the window via the window manager, you will need to bind a function to the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` protocol just as you have done. If you want to ask if they are sure when quitting from a button or menu, you'll have to add the dialog to whatever function those widgets call.

Note that the binding on `<Destroy>` only happens *after* the window has been destroyed, at which time it will be too late to ask for confirmation. You can put code to auto-save in the destroy function, but you'll have to put the confirmation in a function called before the application is destroyed.

### Example

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_destroy(event):
    if event.widget.winfo_parent() == "":
        print("program is exiting...")

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world")
label.pack(fill="both", padx=20, pady=20)
root.bind("<Destroy>", on_destroy)

root.mainloop()
```